# Control AC using FET

Tags: mosfet, ac

[image]

Trying to make a AC fan controller using Arduino and FET ST13005A. Instead of pwm with TRIAC or SSR, like to have fine control over the voltage. Voltage 230 V 50 Hz. Please see if the below simulated schematic is okay.

[Circuit simulator link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#$+1+5.0E-6+6.724437240923179+44+5.0+50%0Ar+432+128+432+208+0+1000.0%0Ar+432+208+432+288+0+1000.0%0Aw+432+208+480+208+2%0Aw+368+128+432+128+0%0Aw+432+128+560+128+0%0Aw+560+128+560+192+2%0Aw+560+224+560+272+0%0Ad+272+128+368+128+1+0.805904783%0Aw+224+128+272+128+2%0Aw+656+288+656+336+1%0Aw+784+224+784+336+0%0Aw+784+128+784+192+2%0Aw+656+128+784+128+0%0Aw+656+208+704+208+2%0Ar+656+208+656+288+0+1000.0%0Ar+656+128+656+208+0+1000.0%0Ad+336+96+272+96+1+0.805904783%0Aw+336+96+656+96+0%0Aw+272+96+272+128+0%0Aw+656+96+656+128+0%0Ad+560+272+560+336+1+0.805904783%0A181+560+336+560+480+0+790.3925183068686+60.0+230.0+1.0+1.0%0Aw+560+336+656+336+0%0Av+224+128+224+352+0+1+50.0+230.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Aw+224+352+432+352+0%0Aw+432+352+432+480+0%0Aw+432+480+560+480+0%0Aw+704+336+784+336+0%0Ac+480+208+480+288+0+4.7E-4+109.9802549530009%0Aw+432+352+480+352+0%0Ad+480+288+480+352+1+0.805904783%0Ad+432+288+432+352+1+0.805904783%0Ac+704+208+704+336+0+4.7E-4+-1.282642963163621%0Aw+704+336+656+336+0%0Af+480+208+560+208+0+1.5%0Af+704+208+784+208+1+1.5%0Ao+21+64+0+35+320.0+0.8+0+-1%0Ao+23+64+0+35+320.0+0.8+1+-1%0A)

Comment: Where's the control signal input? Are you planning to operate the FETs in the linear region, dissipating quite a lot of heat?

Answer (score 1):

Run your simulation and check the power dissipation of the various components - according to a quick check (although I am not familiar with this simulator) I noticed your resistors are dissipating around 11W at peak voltage, and the MOSFETs at least 20W (you would need to check the safe operating area carefully if you plan on operating like this)
So unless you are planning some serious resistors, I think a rethink is probably necessary. The circuir will probably dissipate more power than the fan it's controlling.
Also be aware that 230V is the *RMS value*, the peaks will be 1.41 times that, ~325V. It seems you have set your AC source to 230V peak to peak.

Why do you want to avoid switching?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Switching causes noise thats why. The schematic was just roughly done to test the simulation. Since it worked, I thought of getting suggestion. Found a nice solution given by our good member Tahmid http://www.edaboard.com/entry1816.html

Comment: That solution would still involve switching if you don't want to use large FETs/Heatsinks and want it to be efficient, though if you don't mind the inefficiency then it should work okay, providing you are careful with component selection (i.e. the FET - check the SOA graph in the datasheet, many FETs are not intended for linear operation)